# process is not going background 

Tags: python

I am running the python script shown below. The script does a ssh to the remote machine and runs a c program in the background. But on running the python script I get the following output:

This above means that a.out was run and the pid is [1] 2115 .
However whn I login to the remote machine and check for a.out via 'ps' command I dont see it. 
Another observation is that when i add the delay statement in the python script thread.sleep(20) like , and while the script is still runnuing,
    if I check in the remote machine, a.out is active.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
            import HostMod   #where ssh function is wrote
            COMMAND_PROMPT1 = '[#$] ' 
            p = HostMod.HostModule()
            obj1=p.HostLogin('10.200.2.197', 'root', 'newnet') #ssh connection to remote system
            obj1.sendline ('./a.out > test.txt &') #sending program to remote machine to executethere
            obj1.expect (COMMAND_PROMPT1)
            print obj1.before
            #a.out program 
            int main()
            {
                    while(1)
                    {
                            sleep(10);
                    }

                    return 0;
            }
```

Comment: why not use something like Fabric for ssh?

Answer (score 0):

please try giving absolute path of ./a.out

Comment: i gave with absolute path then also its expected output not comin

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nohup`

```
...
obj1.sendline ('nohup ./a.out > test.txt &') #sending program to remote machine to executethere
```

but you should really not use a shell to invoke commands over ssh. The ssh protocol has builtin support for running commands. I am not sure how your HostMod module works, but you could try this from your shell (would be easy to port to use `subprocess`):

```
ssh somehost nohup sleep 20
<Ctrl+C>

ssh somehost
ps ax | grep sleep
```

And you should see your `sleep` process still running. This method does not instantiate a shell, which is much more reliable, since you may or may not have control over which shell is run, what is in your `~/.(...)rc` files, etc. All in all, much more portable.

Comment: Thank U very much i got the output what i needed